Camera Preview Issue in Android App Developed with Python/KivyMD
I am developing an Android app using Python and KivyMD, and I am facing an issue with the camera preview. Here are the details:
Issue: The camera preview remains black when the app is opened. The preview only displays correctly after I minimize and reopen the app.
I have already set the camera permission in the Buildozer.spec file and granted the permission manually in the device settings after installing the APK.
Code:
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivymd.uix.button import MDButton, MDButtonText, MDButtonIcon
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.dialog import (
    MDDialog,
    MDDialogIcon,
    MDDialogHeadlineText,
    MDDialogSupportingText,
    MDDialogButtonContainer,
    MDDialogContentContainer,
)
from kivymd.uix.divider import MDDivider
from kivymd.uix.list import (
    MDListItem,
    MDListItemLeadingIcon,
    MDListItemSupportingText,
    MDListItemHeadlineText,
    MDListItemTertiaryText,
    MDListItemTrailingCheckbox

)
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from camera4kivy import Preview
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.utils import platform
import os, configparser, requests


class TestCamera(Screen):
    def __init__(self, app, screen_manager, **kwargs):
        super(TestCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex("#0f0d13") 
        self.screen_manager = screen_manager
        self.app = app
        photo_preview = ObjectProperty(None)


    def on_enter(self):
        if self.photo_preview:
            self.photo_preview.connect_camera(enable_analyze_pixels = True)

    def on_pre_leave(self):
        if self.photo_preview:
            self.photo_preview.disconnect_camera()

class Building(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "White"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        sm = ScreenManager()
        
        sm.add_widget(Api(self, screen_manager=sm, name='api'))
        sm.add_widget(Menu(self, screen_manager=sm, name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(TestCamera(self, screen_manager=sm, name='camera'))

        self.dialog = None
        return sm

    def on_start(self):
        global urlAPI

        if platform == 'android':
            from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
            request_permissions([Permission.CAMERA])

        if os.path.exists('api.ini'):
            config = configparser.ConfigParser()
            config.read('api.ini')
            
            if 'URL' in config and 'caminho' in config['URL']:
                urlAPI = config['URL']['caminho']
                self.root.current = 'menu'             
            else:
                self.root.current = 'api'
        else:
            self.root.current = 'api'



It seems that the preview screen does not update when connected to the camera and only updates after the app is minimized and reopened.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Is there a solution or recommendation to resolve this camera preview issue?
I expected the camera preview to start after the on_start method, as suggested in the Git documentation
